# Getting started with FortuneJS

Tags: node.js, json-api

Evening All,

I'm hoping that this is me making a school-boy error. Trying to 'get started' with fortuneJS but having an issue whilst trying to create a new resource.

So, I've setup fortune as described on their [homepage](http://fortunejs.com/). I've opted to use their JSON API plugin, again setup as per their repo.

I'm using Postman to test out the server I've created and I can create a 'user' resource no problem with the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "user",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Andrew"
    }
  }
}
```

That works fine and I get a response as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "users",
    "id": "37446bbc",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Andrew"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "posts": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://localhost:1337/users/37446bbc/relationships/posts",
          "related": "http://localhost:1337/users/37446bbc/posts"
        },
        "data": []
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://localhost:1337/users/37446bbc"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I need to try and create the 'post' resource. Following the JSON API specification I'm posting the following payload:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "posts",
    "attributes": {
      "message": "This is my first post"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": { "type": "users", "id": "37446bbc" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All I get back from that is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "title": "Error",
      "detail": "An internal server error occurred."
    }
  ]
}
```

I've debugged by placing a console log of the 'error' on line 118 in node_modules/fortune/dist/lib/dispatch/index.js which shows this error:

`[TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined]`

Any advice or guidance you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully it's just me!

I'm using `babel-node app.js` to get this running. To save you time, I've thrown up the code onto a [public repo](https://github.com/glanc-ee/fortunejs-example)

Comment: Edited the post create payload to match user IDs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the actual error message needs to be relayed to the client. You can do so by attaching a `catch` to the HTTP listener:

```
const server = http.createServer((request, response) =>
  fortune.net.http(store)(request, response)
  .catch(error => console.log(error.stack)))
```

What I found when I recreated the steps was this:

```
Error: A related record for the field "author" was not found.
```

However, since it is a generic `Error` and not a typed error that Fortune uses internally, it is hidden from the client.

So by setting the correct value for the author `id`, it was able to create a record with that association successfully.

Future versions will be patched so that this informative error message gets shown.

Comment: Sorry, my example was copy and paste heaven. When you set the correct author ID did you not get the `[TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined]` error? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just been having a play around with it again, you're right that the post resource is created but FortuneJS is throwing an error causing the HTTP reply to be 500 with a message of 'An internal server error occurred.'

Answer (score 0):

The originally posted question works fine, the version of node was causing an error. Upgrading to v4.2.1 resolved the issue.